# Why is this \SI{number ^ power}{unit} not allowed?

Tags: siunitx

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[quotient-mode = fraction]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
  \[\SI{1 / 2500 \pi ^ 2}{\micro \farad}\]
\end{document}
```

It produces:

> `siunitx` error: "invalid-token-in-number"

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: `siunitx` expects a number, since it uses a parsing engine. Thus you can't give it stuff it would have to evaluate first. I don't know if there is a way to turn it off, but here you'd probably fare best to git for `\[ {1 / 2500 \pi ^ 2}~\si{\micro \farad} \]`

Comment: @ Timm I assume that the OP does not want to have it evaluated, but just to get \pi squared ...

Comment: @Jürgen: Is assumed that, I intended to use "evaluated" as a more general term for read-and-figure-out-what-it-is. Maybe a question for [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/) ;).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The number parser can be disabled using

```
\SI[parse-numbers=false]{1 / 2500 \pi ^ 2}{\micro \farad}
```

for this single case or generally with

```
\sisetup{parse-numbers = false}
```

As to the 'why' part: the package is focussed on physical quantities, and real measurements cannot delivery `\pi^2` or similar as an outcome, only (here)

```
\SI{3.95e-3}{\micro \farad}
```

or similar

Comment: Though of course if you want to compare  a measured  value  with a theoretical  prediction, you might well want to typeset them  the same  - presumably hence  why it's possible but not the default.

Comment: @ChrisH Perhaps though the _value_ you are comparing will still be a real number

Comment: Personally I use `\si` instead of  `\SI` in  cases like this. Sometimes you do want the units attached to an *exact* real or irrational value.

Comment: It would be interesting if the error message mentioned this option.

Comment: Thank you @Joseph Wright and all other for the answer and comments! When I use `parse-numbers = false` then is the package option `quotient-mode = fraction` is disabled. Can I have both things? Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: @Su-47 No: the point here is that `siunitx`  has a parser for (more-or-less) standard format real numbers, and once you go outside that you have to format by hand: `\frac{1}{2500}\pi^{2}`

Comment: Hello @Joseph Wright! Thank you for your comment! Is this (parser) the reason for [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359061/too-big-space-between-two-digits-when-using-pi-in-si)?