# Too much whitespace between two digits when using \pi in first argument of \SI{}{}

Tags: siunitx

An example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[quotient-mode = fraction]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
  \[\SI{1 / 2500 \pi}{\micro \farad}\]
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: result]

The space between two zeros is clearly too big. Why?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a somewhat tricky-to-parse situation and `siunitx` can't tell that it should not be grouping digits. So you need to turn it off manually

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[quotient-mode = fraction, group-digits = false]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
  \[\SI{1 / 2500 \pi}{\micro \farad}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'll check why the separator is in the wrong place (I suspect an internal mix-up with the fact you've got a fraction), but really this is a case where you don't want the auto-separation anyway

Comment: Hello @Joseph Wright! Thank you for your answer and comment! Your package is great! But maybe it's better for this case to make it locally: `\SI[group-digits = false]{1 / 2500 \pi}{\micro \farad}`. Otherwise (`\usepackage[group-digits = false]{siunitx}`) the nice digit separation is always off.

Comment: Hello @Joseph Wright! The same thing (as in my question above) occours when I type `\SI{250\pi}{\W}`. So not only in fractions. I hope this will help you.